# Wildcard java extends

Tags: java, wildcard, extends

Consider the following code:

```
List<? extends Integer> lst= new ArraList<Integer>();
lst.add(5);//Compile error
lst.get(5);//OK
```

In the second string we have compile error, because we must guaranted have method add(int) in all potencial subtypes of `List<? extends Integer>` and compiler know that its `null` only, third string returns unknow type and compiler cast him to Object, isnt it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: FYI, [`List#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) takes an index.

Comment: Considering `Integer` is `final`, `? extends Integer` is not useful.

Comment: @RohitJain :) Hey, you keep spoiling my game :)) And you spoil my game before I'd type it, so now I seem to be a plagiarist...

Comment: @ppeterka66. Ah! I'll not do it again. ;)

Comment: @RohitJain no offense, of course ;) it's just so funny I write something, refresh, and there it is in the comments :)

Comment: @luiscubal It can be useful (if verbose) marker that a collection is intended to be read-only. Plus, sometimes an API will give you a `List<? extends T>` and doesn't care if `T` is final, so it's still useful to understand, even if the specific use case here is a bit forced (as many concise examples tend to be).

Answer (score 1):

[PECS. Producer extends, Consumer super.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

```
List<? super Integer> lst= new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(5);// No Compile error
```

The list is a **consumer** now, you put objects into it...

Also this

```
lst.get(5);
```

Is a different cake... You provide the Integer **index** of which you want to get... (Not to mention what Sotirios mentioned: the return type will be `Object` in this case. Also, in this role, the list is a **provider**...)

Comment: Note that with the above, `lst.get(x)` returns an object of type `Object`, so you will probably need to cast it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is true, and also, the issue is that the list is a provider in that case... So applying the intersection of the two (the `? extends Integer` and the `? super Integer` sets) leaves the exact `Integer` type to be used in this example...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add anything except `null` to a `List` bounded by a wildcard because you never know the underlying type.

```
List<? extends Integer> lst= new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(5); // Compile error
lst.get(5); // 5 is just the index
```

You can however get an element because you know it must be an `Integer` (in this case).

It's hard to explain with `Integer` because it's a class that cannot be extended. But take this

```
public class Foo {}

public class Bar extends Foo {}

public class Zoop extends Foo {}
```

What could you add to

```
List<? extends Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Zoop>(); // could come from a method
```

?

The list is declared as `? extends Foo` even though the runtime object's generic type is `Zoop`. The compiler therefore cannot let you add anything. But you are guaranteed to be operating on `Foo` objects, so you can retrieve them fine.

Comment: Nitpick: you can add `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `List<? extends Integer>`, the compiler doesn't know whether it's `Integer` or a subtype.  The compiler can't ensure the type safety of adding anything except `null` (really, passing anything to a method taking a generic type parameter, including the `add` method), so it disallows it.  This occurs despite the fact that `Integer` is `final` and no subclasses are allowed.

For the `get` method, the compiler knows that the return type is some kind of `Integer`, so it allows the call and places an implicit cast to `Integer`.